# Design a beam that is straightened with force on one end

Tags: mechanical-engineering, beam

From [here](https://www.quora.com/Bend-a-beam-heavily-Now-freeze-that-geometrical-state-and-get-rid-of-any-tensions-Apply-the-opposite-force-Does-it-have-the-same-horizontal-shape-of-the-beginning), I read that if you have a straight beam, bend it with force at one end, and then create a beam with the resulting curvature, the equal and opposite force *won't* make a straight beam.

- What is the shape of a curved beam that *will* become straight given a point force on the end?

Assume the cross section is rectangular.

Either a closed solution or a way to approximate the shape will do.

**Edit:**

I'm trying to design a spring for a 3d printer.  For technical reasons, printing a 3d helix is difficult.  A design that has a constant cross section in one axis is best.

One design that I've seen is an [zigzag-shaped spring](http://d2q1ebiag300ih.cloudfront.net/uploads/image/file/5254/GM-S-2.jpg).  It seemed to be, however, that the stress isn't evenly distributed, with more strain on the corners and less on the straight parts.

My thought was to make an [eye-shape](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/P/P/y/a/2/j/plain-football-outline-md.png) with pointed corners that compresses to two flat lines.  My intuition is that, if the shape compresses to a flat line then it's spreading the tensile forces evenly and won't break at a weak point.

From the link above, I read that I can't assume a constant $I$ in the Euler-Bernouli beam equation:

$${\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}}{\mathrm {d} x^{2}}}\left(EI{\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}w}{\mathrm {d} x^{2}}}\right)=q $$

[This PDF](http://courses.washington.edu/me354a/Curved%20Beams.pdf) claims that the neutral axis of a curved beam isn't the same as in a straight beam (where it is just the centeroid).  There is a formula for distance of the neutral axis from the inside of the curve:

$$ \text{Height of Neutral Axis} = {\frac h {\ln(r_o / r_i)}} - r_i$$

And the radius of a function $y$ at point $x$ is:

$$R =\left| \frac { \left(1 + y'^{\,2}\right)^{3/2}}{y''}\right|,
\qquad\mbox{where}\quad
y' = \frac{dy}{dx},\quad y'' = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

With those, I hoped to find the shape that, at rest, looks like an eye and when squeezed becomes two flat lines.

Comment: What is this for? A challenge?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is impossible. If you have a horizontal beam with a vertical load at the free end, it will bend such that the tangent at the free end is non-zero. An "equal and opposite" force will still be vertical and will therefore create two components: parallel and perpendicular to the free end, causing both axial and shear forces in the curved beam. Or can the second force be "equal and opposite but perpendicular to the free end"? Also, is this for small or large displacements? Are shear deformations considered?

Comment: To solve the first issue, should this be a non-linear analysis (in which case the first load will already have created axial stresses)?

Comment: The question seems pretty clear to me. The first paragraph is background, see the link. The question is 'What is the shape of a curved beam that will become straight given a point force on the end'. If you haven't seen the link this is referring to an initially curved cantilever loaded by a point load at the end.

Comment: Stretching it out plastically could get it close to straight regardless of initial shape. But this is probably not what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @mg4w Right.  Imagine a drooping cantilever shape.  Make a shape so that, using just upward force on the end, the bar will become completely horizontal.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to create an elliptic leaf spring, right?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf_spring

Comment: Yes, very much like a leaf spring!  A leaf spring gets wider in the middle, however.  I assume that it to balance out the fact that the shear force is greater closer to the center so more stiffness is needed there.  I, however, want to compensate not by increased stiffness but by more complicated shaping.

Comment: @Eyal - Given that you're looking for the equivalent of an elliptic leaf spring, please [edit] that into your question.  And if you added a diagram that shows where you want to apply the force against the spring, that might help clarify your question.  From there, the community should be able to provide an answer letting you know which equation(s) to use for designing the spring.

Comment: To straighten a beam, apply two equal and opposite forces at the two ends axially. Maybe you need to include a sketch on _how_ the force is applied.

Comment: Are you trying to design a spring suitable for a 3D printer or to design/specify a compoent for a 3D printer. If the former I would suggest that 3D printing is a poor way to manufacture springs and you would be much better off using one of the vast array of off the shelf industrial springs which are available which have known mechanical properties and dimensions.

Comment: @ChrisJohns The former and yes, I agree, ABS plastic has lousy elastisity.

Answer (score -1):

$y=\dfrac{Wx^2(3l-x)}{6EI}$ is the equation for deflection of a beam supported at one end and load at the other end ([reference](http://www.engineersedge.com/beam_bending/beam_bending9.htm)).

$E$ is modulus of elasticity. For steels it's 30x10^6 psi

$I$ (moment of inertia) is $\dfrac{bh^3}{12}$ for rectangular sections.

Just design the spring going up by the amount of calculated deflection.

Comment: This is the equation for a straight beam. A curved beam will have different values, as the axial forces wedge against the supports.

Comment: Even without axial force, just perpendicular, the second moment of area isn't the same because the rod is already bent.  The second moment of area is the integral of the square of the distance from the neutral axis and the neutral axis of a bent rod is not at its centeroid.

Comment: ja72, the question included "or a way to approximate the shape will do." Modifying a straight beam by its deflection is a way to approximate the shape.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the answer as a note before starting the answer